# Resource not found in ResourceDictionary for external control

Tags: xaml, uwp, resourcedictionary

**PROBLEM**

I would like to style control that is defined in Project B, but used on page in Project A using styles from Project A. I decided to do it by defining Merged Dictionary with styles dictionary that contains keys used in MyCtrl.xaml.

I thought that MyCtrl that is used in MainPage will go up the XAML tree to find the right style if it didn't find it in own xaml (broader scope), but I get exceptions that name/key was not found. Am I doing something wrong, or this idea is incorrect and I should find another solution?

**Here is the structure:**

I have a 2 projects:

- Project A - main application with MainPage page and all styles/resources.
- Project B - contains user controls

Project A references Project B.

**(Project A) MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
   xmlns:ext="using:ProjB.Ctrls">
  <Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///SomeDir/MyCtrlStyles.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///SomeDir/MainPageStyles.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </Page.Resources>
  …
  <ext: MyCtrl x:Id="myCtrlA" />
  …
</Page>
```

**(Project A) MainPageStyles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="StyleAAA" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**(Project A) MainPageStyles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="StyleBBB" BasedOn="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="24 13 12 0" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**(Project B) MyCtrl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <TextBlock x:Name="txtA" Style="{StaticResource StyleBBB}" Text="Text A" />
</ UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the source path should be:

> ms-appx:///[Assembly]/[Path]/[Resource File]

So you should add the assembly name to the referenced assembly, like this:

```xml
<Page
   xmlns:ext="using:ProjB.Ctrls">
  <Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyCtrl/SomeDir/MyCtrlStyles.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///SomeDir/MainPageStyles.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </Page.Resources>
  …
  <ext: MyCtrl x:Id="myCtrlA" />
  …
</Page>
```

Comment: The key problem is that styles are not in assembly B, but in assembly A. Only custom control MyCtrl comes from assembly B.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ext: MyCtrl x:Id="myCtrlA" />
```

is just an instance of your custom control, in a different project with no knowledge of the styles you are trying to use.

Since the xaml for your custom control must be loaded before it can be instantiated, it will try to find the resource StyleBBB at that time. The resource cannot be found because the resource is not in any dictionary available to it, or the app.xaml merged dictionaries.

Some options, in the order I would recommend trying them.

**Option 1**

You should try using DynamicResource.

This will allow the binding to revevaluate when the control is placed into the page, so it can properly look it up at runtime.

DynamicResource is moderately more performance demanding, so if this is a control you plan on creating thousands of instances of all the time, this could be too much of a tradeoff.

**Option 2**

Place the merged dictionaries into your app.xaml file.

This application wide resource dictionary can be considered a fallback lookup when a resource cannot be found elsewhere.

The downside is that it's available to everything in your application, and it only works for one resource of any given key, so you can't just override it in a sub-control like you normally can.

**Option 3**

Add a reference to Project A into Project B. Merge the dictionary you need into the resources of your control.

This adds a dependency you didn't have before, and it's circular, so try not to do this.